# Multiple parameters in NSURL object

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsurl

I would like to pass multiple parameters from the iphone sdk to a server-side php which interfaces with a mySQL database.

i found some answers on how to do this, but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to include several parameters.

what i have right now is

---

```
- (IBAction)sendButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://server.com/file.php?date=%d", theDate];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstr];

    [urlstr release];
    [url release];
}
```

---

which would work for 1 parameter, but what i'm looking for would be something like

```
http://server.com/file.php?date=value&time=value&category=value&tags=value&entry=value
```

how would i going about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `- initWithFormat` method takes multiple arguments for the format string.

So you can do things like this:

```
  NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://server.com/file.php?date=%d&second=%d&third=%d", theDate, 2, thirdIVar];
```

`- initWithFormat` works almost identically to `printf()` and it variants.

Here is some `printf()` examples http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=csc02

Edit: Where are the variables `nameField, tagsField, dreamEntry` defined and set?

Unless they are `NSString`s and defined in the `@interface` you can not uses them in this way.

I suggest hard coding some values for testing:

```
    NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://server.com/file.php?date=%@&time=%@&name=%@&category=%d&tags=%@&entry=%@", nil, nil, @"Name", nil, @"Tags", @"Dream"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an NSURL doesn't open communications with a server. It's just a data structure for holding a URL. You want to read up on [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Are all the variables you're passing in your format really numbers? `%d` is the placeholder for a number; `%@` is an object. It's very surprising to be passing nil if you're expecting a number, even for testing purposes. It'll "work" because nil is 0, but it suggests that these aren't really numbers.

Comment: considering that in this case the communication should work only one-way... the iphone doesn't get data back from the server, it just sends it, what might be missing for this to work?

i switched placeholders accordingly, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Creating an NSURL is like creating an NSString. It doesn't cause it to be output anywhere. You still need to connect to the server. That's what NSURLConnection does. Even though you don't want any data back, you're going to get something. At the very least you hope to get an HTTP/200, right?